# Google Home Security Testing

Tags: actions-on-google

I want to develop actions for Google Home but would like to know whether user interacting with the device is the same person whose account is linked with my service. As my service will include confidential information and money transfer capabilities as well so don't want the device to be misused by someone to know confidential information or for transferring money. So is there any security measures for this in Google Home?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, there is essentially no security from google home (except for prohibiting access to private information, like your calendar, altogether). Google Home does not recognize the voice of who's talking to it, so it won't tell the difference between you, your spouse or a thief.

There are rumors that voice recognition (different from speech recognition) might be added eventually, and handling of multiple user accounts. Even if that were the case, I doubt that provides enough security for something as sensitive as money transfers. Obviously, you could implement your own security layer, though. (E.g., ask for a pass phrase before executing a transaction. This should probably use one-time use passwords / tokens, though, so that anyone who overhears the phrase won't be able to use it.)